# What is the oxidation state of oxygen in hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: oxidation-state, hydrogen

In Hydrogen peroxide, the oxidation number of oxygen is "-1" instead of "-2".

[image: Da pic]

But it seems to me that, the oxygen atoms have '-2' as their oxidation number as each oxygen atom here is connected to a hydrogen atom **and** an oxygen atom.

So, what's actually happening here?

Comment: Here is another way to think about it. Mentally break the O-O bond heterolytically (+/-). Now you have HO- and HO+. HO- has a -2 charge (normal) and HO+ has a zero charge on oxygen since in both cases hydrogen is +1. Oxygen zero, a 2-electron oxidant, will accept 2-electrons from a reducing agent to convert HO+ to HO-. This is why HOOH is an oxidant. E.g., MeSMe + HOOH --->  Me2SO  +  H2O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each oxygen atom is connected to a hydrogen atom(which develops -1 charge on oxygen and +1 on hydrogen) and to another $\textbf{oxygen}$ atom which contributes no charge to both(0 and 0). Similar for other oxygen atom. Hence oxygen state of each oxygen atom is -1 and for each hydrogen atom it is +1.

In general, in peroxide linkage, oxygen has -1 oxidation state